# Assigning a variable in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables

So i am writing a program for practice and needed some help with a for loop, The program takes the amount of people buying, the amount being brought and then the total money being paid.

Once it takes this it outputs the price per item

What i would like to happen next is for the program to use the amount of people stored in "GroupNo" to output the question "How much money has Person 1 put in, How much has person 2 put in"........ etc until it gets to the amount the user inputed.

**I know to get the loop to output the question the right amount of times, its a simple case of "for i in range (0, GroupNo)" but how do i get each answer to this question to be stored in a new variable each time it is asked**

```
GroupNo = int(input("How many people are buying?"))
Gs = int(input("How many are you picking up?"))
Ps = int(input("How much money is being paid?"))
PPG = Ps / Gs
print ("Price per item is:" ,"£",PPG,)

def MainCalc():
    for i in range (0, GroupNo):
        int(input("How Much is person 1 paying:")) #This would increment up till it hits GroupNo
MainCalc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to use a dictionary with the iteration as the key

```
def main_calc():
    payments = dict()
    for i in range(1, GroupNo + 1):
        value = input(f"How Much is person {i} paying: ")
        payments[i] = int(value)

    return payments


# example code
data = main_calc()

print(data) # view entire dictionary
print(data[1]) # view only person 1
```

Comment: Thank you, so GroupNo + 1 means add one every time it loops and what is the cheeky f for on line 4

Comment: in python, range is exclusive meaning if you don't specify a starting integer it begins at 0. I specified that so rather than starting at person0 we start at person1.

Comment: they're stored in whatever variable you assign to your maincalc function. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: i see, thank you for this help but i have another question, how to i access each item in the dictionary and use them in different calculations, for example if i wanted to divide the first number in the list into the "Ps"

Comment: dictionary values are accessed by their keys, in this case an integer between 1 and GroupNo --  https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#accessing-dictionary-values

Please mark the answer as solved if I was able to help out!